# Finding object using NSDictionary valueForKey vs. iterating through NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, cocoa, nsarray

I'm working on a simple iOS caching system for some images. I need to keep track of the UIImage itself and its identifier. Now, I'm trying to figure out which is a faster/more efficient way to access the correct cached image.

Option 1:

```
for (CachedImage* image in [cachedImageArray]
{
  if ([[image identifier] isEqualToString:@"id_12345"]
  { 
    // use that image
  }
}
```

Option 2:

```
UIImage* imageToRetrieve = [cachedImagesDictionary objectForKey:@"id_12345"
```

Is there any benefit from using one method or the other? And if so, is it non-negligible? Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit tangential to the question you asked, but you should probably check out [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any benefit from using one method or the other?

Yes.

```
UIImage *imageToRetrieve = [cachedImagesDictionary objectForKey:@"id_12345"];
```

is **much more readable.**

(Oh, you meant performance? Don't worry about that. Premature optimization is the root of almost all evil.)

Comment: @DanF Thanks. Yes, one of my favorites.

Comment: Don't forget you can also use this notation, making it even more concise: `UIImage *imageToRetrieve = cachedImagesDictionary[@"id_12345"];`

Comment: @DanF Yes :) But I like backwards-compatibility (and anyway, to be honest, I always forget that notation, despite it being awesome).

Comment: I did, because I think the part in brackets is badly worded and makes it an overall misleading answer. Premature optimization might be evil, choosing the right data structure (nothing fancy, we're talking NSArray, NSDictionary or NSSet here) for the job is not. The fear of premature optimization is no reason to make terrible design decisions.

Answer (score 7):

Dictionaries will most likely be faster, since they'll use some hashing algorithm to make the retrieval efficient (usually `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`). It will be non-negligible if the number of elements in your cache is large.

from [CFDictionary.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-368.18/Collections.subproj/CFDictionary.h)

> Computational Complexity
>   The access time for a value in the dictionary is guaranteed to be at
>       worst O(lg N) for any implementation, current and future, but will
>       often be O(1) (constant time). Insertion or deletion operations
>       will typically be constant time as well, but are O(N*lg N) in the
>       worst case in some implementations. Access of values through a key
>       is faster than accessing values directly (if there are any such
>       operations). Dictionaries will tend to use significantly more memory
>       than a array with the same number of values.

Comment: Agreed, the dictionary should be, at worst `O(log(n))`

Comment: "Dictionaries will be faster" - I assume you just benchmarked it, right?

Comment: For small number of data, the performance difference will be negligible. For large number of entries, one can always find some convoluted case (hash collisions) where the dictionary will be slower. So @H2CO3 you win, I rewrote it to not be so categoric :)

Comment: Great, and just to note, I'm probably not going to have more than a couple hundred entries at a time anyway.

Comment: I added some statement from CFDictionary.h. I hope you dont mind.

Answer (score 1):

Like H2CO3 says, I'd choose Option 2 for readability.

However, if it's truly a cache (i.e. you're happy for the OS to automatically remove objects from the cache if memory is tight), I'd use [`NSCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) over `NSDictionary`:

```
// Setup the cache
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blah"];
NSCache *imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
[imageCache setObject:myImage forKey:@"id_12345"];   

// Sometime later...
UIImage* imageToRetrieve = [imageCache objectForKey:@"id_12345"];
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll look into NSCache. It wouldn't flush every 5mb or anything though, right?

Comment: The docs are rather vague on exactly when the cache is cleared, but in my experience it doesn't happen often. Still, you'll need to ensure you can refresh the cache if needed. I believe you can control when objects are evicted using `evictsObjectsWithDiscardedContent` & `<NSDiscardableContent>`, but as per [Mattt's advice](http://nshipster.com/nscache), it's probably more trouble than it's worth.